# Not passing data PHP

Tags: php

My code isn't working

```
mysql_query( 'INSERT INTO RegUsuarios ( Nombre,Email,PW ) values 
("$_POST[Nombre]","$_POST[Email]","$_POST[PW]")' , $Con ) or 
die('Problema insertando los datos');
```

I know that it is this line because everything else is working

Answer (score 2):

You cant process PHP code inside single speech marks, only in doubles.

Either swap all your singles for doubles or else do this `"'.$_POST['Nombre'].'"`

Comment: @IsraelJiménez no prob, dont forget to click the green tick if this helped you!

Comment: Tough he should not use `$_POST` directly in the query, always escape user input due to SQL injection issues. Also the `mysql_` functions are deprecated, the `mysqli` functions or `PDO` should be used.

Comment: @TheCandyMan Yes. Solution above is just a quick fix, but the code has many problems as you pointed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO RegUsuarios (Nombre,Email,PW) values ('$_POST[Nombre]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[PW]')",$Con);
```

As a good practice,always use `'` inside `"` and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query( 'INSERT INTO RegUsuarios ( Nombre,Email,PW ) values ("$_POST[Nombre]","$_POST[Email]","$_POST[PW]")' , $Con ) or die('Problema insertando los datos');
```

should be

```
mysql_query( 'INSERT INTO RegUsuarios ( Nombre,Email,PW ) values (\''.$_POST[Nombre].'\',\''.$_POST[Email].'\',\''.$_POST[PW].'\')' , $Con ) or die('Problema insertando los datos');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO RegUsuarios (Nombre,Email,PW) values ('$_POST[Nombre]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[PW]')",$Con) or die('Problema insertando los datos');
```

try the above query. Double quotes replaced by single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

use this $_POST['Nombre'] in quotes 'Nombre' ....

```
INSERT INTO RegUsuarios (Nombre,Email,PW) values ('$_POST['Nombre']','$_POST['Email']','$_POST['PW']')',$Con) or die('Problema insertando los datos');
```

Comment: $_POST['Nombre']  it is not invalid... I didn't tested the query, but quotes in $_POST give error if not present.

Comment: `'$_POST['Nombre']',` has to be like `'$_POST[Nombre]',`

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not properly assembled (as others pointed).

That's the minor problem with your code. The major problem is that your example is prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) because you don't perform any input data sanitisation. Here's a question (and answer) that covers this subject: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)